# Visual Studio 2012 IIS 7 - JavaScript File Lock

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, iis-7

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to develop an MVC 4 web application. I have also created a virtual directory on my local IIS 7 server which points to my MVC application. Both IIS and Visual Studio 2012 point to the same source code.

I usually edit JavaScript files and hit refresh on my browser to reload the JavaScript file.

For some reason whenever I edit the JavaScript via Visual Studio 2012 it is write protected (by IIS) so I have to touch the web.config file in order for IIS to release the file in order to overwrite the file. This is really annoying when debugging because I have to reload the application every time I make a minor change to a JavaScript file.

Has anyone had this issue and how did you resolve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: I would be using IIS Express as my development server, as opposed to IIS itself.